# How to load a word2vec txt file with vocabulary constraint

Tags: gensim

I have a word2vec file in the standard format, but it is huge with 2M items. I also have a vocabulary file where each row is a word, the file has about ~800K rows. Now I want to load the embeddings from the word2vec file, and I want only embeddings for words in the vocabulary file. Is there an efficient implementation in gensim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in support for filtering the words on load. But you could use the code for the `load_word2vec_format()` function as a model for your own alternate loading code that skips words not-of-interest.

You can view the code for that function in the `KeyedVectors` class...

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ff107d6c5cb50d9ab99999cb898ff0aceb192592/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1434

...and some shared support functions...

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ff107d6c5cb50d9ab99999cb898ff0aceb192592/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py#L294

Comment: I decided to take the following approach:

1) use subprocess to call bash commands that write a tmp file. The tmp file includes only embeddings of words that appear in the vocab file

2) simply load the tmp file by calling `load_word2vec_format()`